# Overwriting dynamically allocated memory-C++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I'm working on an assignment right now where we create our own basic, dynamically allocated vector struct. One of the functions we are supposed to make is a function to extend the vector when the user enters values.

```
struct Vector{//vector structure
    unsigned int size;
    Elem *svector;
};

Vector *extend_vec(Vector *extend,Elem element){
    if (extend==NULL){
        return NULL;}


    Elem *tempVec=new Elem[(*extend).size];

    memcpy(tempVec,(*extend).svector,sizeof((*extend).svector));//copies memory from the original array to the temp array

    (*extend).size+=1;

    delete[] (*extend).svector;//clears the memory

    (*extend).svector=new Elem[(*extend).size];//reallocates with the new size


}
```

Elem=float btw**

My question is whether this line is necessary, and why :

```
 delete[] (*extend).svector;//clears the memory
```

I'm a bit hazy on how memory is overwritten/reallocated in a situation like this. I'm not sure if reallocating overwrites whats already there.

**So I read through everyone's comments and this is what I came up with.

```
Vector *extend_vec(Vector *extend,Elem element){
    if (extend==NULL){
            return NULL;}


    Elem *tempVec=new Elem[extend->size+1];
    tempVec[extend->size+1]=element;

     memcpy(tempVec,extend->svector,(extend->size*sizeof(Elem)));//copies the memory from the original array to the rest of the temp array

    extend->size+=1;

    delete[] extend->svector;//clears the memory

    extend->svector=tempVec;//the original vector now becomes the extended vector

    delete[] tempVec;//clears the temporary memory

    return extend;
}
```

Comment: How this `(*extend).svector=new Elem[(*extend).size];//reallocates with the new size` gets old values? Could you provide full sample?

Comment: What is the second argument `element` for? You don't use it.

Comment: using memcpy in this context may give you problems e.g. if the 'Elem' contains pointers to allocated storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the code presented here will work as expected. I think what you want is:

```
Elem *tempVec = new Elem[extend->size +1];
tempVec[extend->size] = element;
memcpy(tempVec, extend->svector, extend->size);
delete[] extend->svector;
extend->svector = tempVec;
extend->size += 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not overwriting anything, you're allocating a new, longer array to be used in place of the old array. So you need to delete the old array once you're done with it.

However, the last line of your function is wrong. You copied the the contents of the old `svector` array into `tempVec`, but instead of using this to replace `svector` you allocate another array. The last line should be:

```
extend->svector = tempVec;
```

One other thing: Since your function is declared to return Vector*, you need a `return extend;` statement after that.

BTW, I think `ptr->member` is the preferred style rather than `(*ptr).member`.

Answer (score 1):

the line `delete[] (*extend).svector;//clears the memory` is necessary also you need to release `tempVec` as well  `delete [] tempVec;`

Comment: No, he need to save `tempVec` in the Vector.

Comment: he can either do memcpy tempVec to (*extend).svector or assign tempVec to (*extend).svector.

Comment: The first would be silly. He's already done the memcpy, why do it again?

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in the code you posted.

This will allocate enough space for the Vector's *current* size you probably want (*extend).size + 1

```
    Elem *tempVec=new Elem[(*extend).size];
```

This will only copy the bytes required to store a pointer, i.e. sizeof((*extend).svector),

```
    memcpy(tempVec,(*extend).svector,sizeof((*extend).svector));//copies memory from the original array to the temp array
```

you should copy all the bytes previously stored, that is `(*extend).size * sizeof(Elem)`

```
    (*extend).size+=1;
```

This returns the previously reserved memory to the runtime. You have to do this for every `new[]` you make.

```
    delete[] (*extend).svector;//clears the memory
```

Next, this is pointing to yet another block of allocated memory.. but *not* the block you had previously copied into. This should probably have been `(*extend).svector = tempVec;`

```
    (*extend).svector=new Elem[(*extend).size];//reallocates with the new size
```

Finally, you're never copying the new value into the newly allocated space! That is, you're missing something like

```
    (*extend).svector[(*extend).size - 1] = element;
```